# prove that there is some number $x$ such that $x^{179}+\frac{163}{1+x^2+\sin^2x}=119$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

prove that there is some number x such that $ x^{179}+\frac{163}{1+x^2+\sin^2x}=119$

I really want to know the general process to prove something like that...

Comment: Sounds like Intermediate Value Theorem...

Comment: You have a continuous function over $I=[0,2]$ that ranges from $0$ to a huge number. $119$ is somewhere between.

Comment: @pyrazolam Of course, you don't even really need to "find" one, in any useful sense of "find."

Comment: In this particular case, we have a solution near $1.0231634$.

Comment: I definitely know there exists a point, and by using the calculator, I can even try to track the number.. But, since this one is proof-based question...I want to know the specific steps to prove it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First notice $1+x^2+\sin^2(x)\geq 1$ so the denominator is never $0$ and the function $f(x)=x^{179}+\frac{163}{1+x^2+\sin^2(x)}-119$ is defined and continuous everywhere.

$f(2)>2^{179}-119>0$, $f(-2)<-2^{179}+163-119<0$ so by intermediate value theorem there is a $x_0\in (-2,2)$ satisfies $f(x_0)=0$, which is the solution of the equation given.

Comment: So, basically, I just need to find two x, such that f(x1)<119<f(x2) while ensuring that the function is continuous, right?

Comment: @Flying Birds:  Right!

Comment: I previously thought there is a more rigorous proof process. Now, it makes sense.

Comment: @FlyingBirds When your question has an answer that satisfies you the right way to thank the answerer is to accept the answer. You can also upvote it, and upvote other acceptable answers (even though you can accept just one).

Comment: ..umm, I'm unsure how to accept the answer. I didn't find that option. Could you plz be more specific about how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The dominating term is $x^{179}$, so as $x\to\pm\infty$, $f(x)\to\pm\infty$. In particular, the intermediate Value Theorem guarantees the existence of at least one $x$ such that $f(x)=c$ for any given $c\in\Bbb R$.